# nokogiri run well but doesn't return anything

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Hi and thanks for reading !

I'm learning how to use xpath and nokogiri and I followed same instructions than [the tutorial on Engine Yard](https://blog.engineyard.com/getting-started-with-nokogiri).

I copy / paste exactly the same code, it runs well on terminal and ended (no error message are returned) but nothing is returned. It should return all the titles with hyperlink but actually it just ended like there is nothing to return.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open("http://www.google.com/search?q=doughnuts"))

doc.xpath('//h3/a').each do |node|
    puts node.text
end

# puts doc.class
```

I tried `puts doc.class` instead of `puts node.text` and it did the same thing (run well, ended without errors, return nothing)

I also tried `puts doc.class` instead of

```
doc.xpath('//h3/a').each do |node|
    puts doc.class
end
```

and it return well : "Nokogiri::HTML::Document" so problem come from my xpath but i don't know why...

If someone can help me with this, I'll be glad ! :)

Answer (score 0):

looking in google page structure, the 'h3' element is inside 'a' element. You can try something like this. I think its will work.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(URI.open("http://www.google.com/search?q=doughnuts"))

doc.xpath('//h3').each do |node|
  puts node.text
  puts node.parent.xpath('./@href')
end
```

Comment: It would ! Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Please, mark answer as useful if it helps you.

Comment: I unfortunately can't : I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but my feedback has been recorded.